# NSFetchedResultsController cache makes the table upside down

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:self.photoDatabase.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"status" cacheName:nil];
```

if I set this cache to something like `@"fetch_cache"` then my table is upside down. Section 1 is above section 0!

I'm new to CoreData. What should I know about this?

Update: I have a sort descriptor and it works. Forgot to put it here.

Answer (score 0):

There's no implicit ordering in Core Data, so you probably need to tell the controller how you want these objects ordered.

Take a look at `NSSortDescriptor` and call `-setSortDescriptors:` on your `NSFetchRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

`sectionNameKeyPath` only specifies the grouping, it does not sort those objects for you. You have to add an `NSSortDescriptor` to your `request`.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't post it but I have a working sort descriptor defined for the request. And the request works fine while caching is nil. But when I add a cache file it suddenly goes upside down.

Comment: As from [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), make sure that the first item in your `NSSortDescriptor` array properly sorts the objects by `@"status"`. Also from the same page: `If you are using a cache, you must call deleteCacheWithName: before changing any of the fetch request, its predicate, or its sort descriptors. You must not reuse the same fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the cacheName to nil.`